# How to run a function after the enpoint is completed?

Tags: angular, typescript

On click of the next button I am calling an endpoint and after that I am routing the page to `/newPage` but I need the `storeCardsSystem` to save a data to session from the response. I need that data in session before routing.

I am facing problem because I get undefined in session because of the async call in the service. I tried calling the `this.customRouter.navigate(["/newPage"])` from the `onComplete` block in the service but is there any other way where I can keep the `this.customRouter.navigate(["/newPage"])` in the component and wait for the service call to complete before routing without using `timeouts`.

Component:

```
 public nextClick(): void {
    this.issuerServiceMappingService.getMappingService(this.param);
    this.customRouter.navigate(["/newPage"]);
 }
```

Service:

```
getMappingService(param: string) {
  this.getServiceMappingDetails(servicesMappingRequest).subscribe(res => {
    this.storeCardsSystem(res.cardsSystem);
  }, 
  () => {},
  () => {
     // onComplete
  })
}
```

Comment: Is this call async to?   this.storeCardsSystem(res.cardsSystem);

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling it would be like this. Of course I had more context of the code it can be made more cleaner but that's appropriate in this context as well

```
public nextClick(): void {
    this.issuerServiceMappingService.getMappingService(this.param).subscribe(res => {
    this.storeCardsSystem(res.cardsSystem);
  }, 
  () => {},
  () => {
     // onComplete
    this.customRouter.navigate(["/newPage"]);
  })
}

 }
```

```
getMappingService(param: string) {
 return this.getServiceMappingDetails(servicesMappingRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

> First, you have to import router in your service constructor

```
constructor {
 ...
 private router: Router,
 ...
}
```

> Second, update your method

```
getMappingService(param: string) {
 this.getServiceMappingDetails(servicesMappingRequest)
  .pipe(
   take(1) # Just to avoid memory leaks or unsubscribe using your methods
  )
  .subscribe(res => {
   this.storeCardsSystem(res.cardsSystem);
   this.router.navigateByUrl("/newPage");
  })
}
```

I hope this helps you !